# Visual Studio - Configure Data Source - Non-dbo Schema Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, stored-procedures, schema, dbo

I work for a large company with big data and we have a data architecture where we mostly use non-dbo schemas. When I use Visual Studio (2013 Ultimate) and the Configure Data Source feature, it only lists stored procedures in the dbo schema. The ones I need are located in other schemas (rpt., adm., usr., etc.). Is there a configuration setting or some other way to get access to non-dbo resources?

Comment: Are you sure you have permission to these other schemas? It really sounds like just a simple permissions issue.

Comment: You don't need any extra setting to work with other schemas. The Data Source window shows objects in non-dbo schemas as "name (schema)".

Comment: Read this article about "default schema".  Most likely ( as already stated ) is a (lack of) permissions issues.  https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-training/schema-based-access-control-for-sql-server-databases/

Comment: I logged into this server via SSMS using the connectionstring credentials provided for this project and could see all stored procedures on all schemas (and successfully executed several on non-dbo schemas). Double-checked the permissions assigned to this role and it shows all necessary privileges. Hummm. Must be missing something somewhere.

Comment: BTW, I'm using VS2013Ultimate connecting into SQL Server 2014 Standard Edition (since we are using standard edition which can only access 16 CPU cores and our dev/test/prod db servers run on 32-core servers, we have the default SQL instance (OLTP-optimized) running on first 16-cores and a named instance (SOLAP-optimized) running on the second bay of 16-cores). I'm connecting into the default instance. Seemingly a straightforward configuration.